# Telegram bot: a dirctionary of available commands

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How to organize a dictionary of available commands for a Telegram bot? How do good programmers do it? I know that writing dozens of `if` statements is a bad idea, as well as a `switch` statement.

For now it's implemented using `switch`:

1. The bot receives a command
2. Finds it in a `switch`
3. Processes the command
4. Sends the response to the user

But when there are dozens of commands, the `switch` operator becomes hard to maintain. What is the common way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Python coder, but it seems that your problem should be solved with with an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) data structure regardless the language you use. The actual name of the structure may vary from language to language: for example, in C++ it is called `map`, and in Python it is.. [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)! Thus, you several times wrote the relevant keyword in your question (even in the original language).

Bearing the above in mind, a sketch of your program may look like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

# Command processing functions:
def func1():
    return "Response 1"

def func2():
    return "Response 2"

# Commands dictionary:
d = {"cmd1":func1, "cmd2":func2}

# Suppose this command was receiced by the bot:
command_received = "cmd1"

# Processing:
try:
    response = d[command_received]()
except KeyError:
    response = "Unknown command"

# Sending response:
print response
```

Comment: I would like to add that good example will be router implementation in Python's server-side frameworks like [Django](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/).